# How to properly change dtype of numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy array that I obtained from pandas dataframe

```
data_array = df['column_name'].to_numpy()
```

The resulting array has dtype object, just like the original column, and consists of lists of integer values with shape (2000,). I would like it be of int32 type. However when I attempt to use

```
data_array = data_array.astype(np.int32)
```

I get exception

```
setting an array element with a sequence.
```

All elements in array are lists with same number of integers (a hundred or so).

The general format is:

```
[[1,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1]]
```

Is there something obvious I'm missing? Or is there another, better way, to convert pandas dataframes into numpy arrays of desired type?

Because it seems to me I'm running out of options.

### EDIT

I figured it out, although the approach was a bit hacky.

```
data_array = np.array(df['column_name'].to_list(), np.int32)
```

I'm still not sure why it was needed. But apparently one can turn two dimensional list of integers to numpy array with the right dtype and a list of numpy arrays instead of the two dimensional list.

Comment: "and consists of lists of integer values" A list of integer values cannot be converted to `dtype=np.int32`. It is *a list*. Why are you working with `list` objects in a `pandas.DataFrame` to begin with? Anyway, you need to post a [mcve]

Comment: So `data_array` is object dtype and 1d?   If so `np.stack(data_array)` may produce a 2d array with a numeric dtype.  If that doesn't work it's likely that the lists do differ in length.

Comment: Yes, if it is already an object array of lists, calling `np.array` on that won't change it.  That's why I suggested `stack`.  But converting it to a list of lists works, and in some cases is more robust.